# OutOfMemory при создании screenshot в Android

Tags: android, bitmap, экран, скриншот

Пытаюсь сделать скриншот. Подсказали пару методов

```
 protected Bitmap MakeScreenshotOfView(View v)
{
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int totalHeight, int totalWidth) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth,totalHeight , Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.measure( View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(totalWidth,View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(totalHeight,View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    view.layout(0,0,totalWidth,totalHeight);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Оба работают на простых экранах, где не много View. Но мне надо сделать скрин Вот такого экрана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он динамически заполняется небольшими ImageView. Происходит потом анимация. в конце анимации пытаюсь сделать скрин, он думает и потом выдает OOM.

```
06-24 18:40:29.700 4166-4186/com.appache.fingerdynamometersimulator I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 24(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 468MB/468MB, paused 19.281ms total 76.606ms at GCDaemon thread CareAboutPauseTimes 1
06-24 18:40:29.855 4166-4186/com.appache.fingerdynamometersimulator I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(560B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 470MB/486MB, paused 20.558ms total 77.170ms at GCDaemon thread CareAboutPauseTimes 1
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1704972 byte allocation with 908240 free bytes and 886KB until OOM
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:842)
                                                                                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:812)
```

Первые две строчки много раз повторяются с разными значениями и потом вылетает.
HELP!!!

Comment: попробуйте добавить к тегу `application` атрибут `android:largeHeap="true"` в манифесте. Это не совсем правильное решение, но если сработает - самое простое

Comment: Пробовал - не помогает. Как раз хотелось бы понять в чем может быть дело. Не сказать, что я ем много памяти, обычный фрэйм, динамически добавляю к слоям штук 20 image view общим размером 1Мб...

Comment: а телефон рутованный? Если да то попробуйте что-то в духе `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png"});`